# What is kernel_version=4.X.Y-Z?

Tags: sd-card, beagleboard

I am following this [link](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-InstallKernelandRootFileSystem)
 to create a bootable SD card.  I am stuck at `kernel_version=4.X.Y-Z`.

What do I do with this whole thing here:

```
-----------------------------
Script Complete
eewiki.net: [user@localhost:~$ export kernel_version=4.X.Y-Z]
-----------------------------
```

Next, I don't quite get this:

```
Copy and paste that "export kernel_version=4.X.Y-Z" exactly as shown in your own build/desktop environment....
```

What is the build/desktop environment?  Do I use this:

```
export kernel_version=4.X.Y-Z
```

Or this ('uname -r' gives me this --> 4.10.0-42-generic):

```
export kernel_version=4.10.0-42-generic
```

Next, I encounter a problem with this (after using kernel as shown by uname):

```
sudo tar xfvp ./*-*-*-armhf-*/armhf-rootfs-*.tar -C /media/rootfs/
```

It complains:

```
tar: ./*-*-*-armhf-*/armhf-rootfs-*.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

### What have I done wrong?  Thank you in advance.

So I search the computer, and found this file:

```
/home/administrator/ti-linux-kernel-dev/debian-9.3-minimal-armhf-2017-12-09/armhf-rootfs-debian-stretch.tar
```

Thus, I change the command to:

```
sudo tar xfvp /home/administrator/ti-linux-kernel-dev/debian-9.3-minimal-armhf-2017-12-09/armhf-rootfs-debian-stretch.tar -C /media/rootfs/
```

This command executes.  I suppose I am doing it right?

Comment: OK, `uname -r` gives me `4.10.0-42-generic`.  However, the zImage shows `4.9.73-bone-rt-r9`.  I suppose I should go with the latter one?  How come they are different?

Comment: So does this mean the command should be `export kernel_version=4.9.73-bone-rt-r9`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after `./build_kernel.sh`, there is this output at the end:

```
-----------------------------
'arch/arm/boot/zImage' -> '/home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/4.9.73-bone-rt-r9.zImage'
'.config' -> '/home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/config-4.9.73-bone-rt-r9'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.4M Jan  1 00:06 /home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/4.9.73-bone-rt-r9.zImage
-----------------------------
Building modules archive...
Compressing 4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-modules.tar.gz...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20M Jan  1 00:06 /home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-modules.tar.gz
-----------------------------
Building firmware archive...
Compressing 4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-firmware.tar.gz...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jan  1 00:06 /home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-firmware.tar.gz
-----------------------------
Building dtbs archive...
Compressing 4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-dtbs.tar.gz...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 487K Jan  1 00:06 /home/administrator/bb-kernel/deploy/4.9.73-bone-rt-r9-dtbs.tar.gz
-----------------------------
Script Complete
eewiki.net: [user@localhost:~$ export kernel_version=4.9.73-bone-rt-r9]
-----------------------------
```

So `export kernel_version=4.9.73-bone-rt-r9` is right.